# What is the right way to test CSV-related method. Rspec

Tags: ruby

I have a CSV writing method that looks like this:

```
def self.write(output_path:, data:)
    CSV.open(output_path, "w") do |csv|
      data.each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
```

In general, I want to stub the `CSV` class and I want to make sure the right inputs get send to the method. How do I test that we iterate through data and each row gets send to the csv object? What do I do here to test this?

My plan is to determine what the `csv` that is yielded is, stub that with an `instance_double` and check to see if it receives `:<<` with each piece of data that I iterate through. However, the `csv` object is:

```
<#CSV io_type:File io_path:"./public/output/redemptions.csv" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:1 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"">
```

What is that? How do I stub that? I tried stubbing it with an instance_double of `CSV` but that did not work and it complained that it received an unexpected method of `<<`. Any advice?

Comment: can you show your attempt at stubbing